# Calulate a series of many slopes

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I have a list of coordinates and i currently have a function that deals with said coordinates to find the slope, all in order and paired

```
public void foo(){

    int[] xCoords = {//stuff}
    int[] yCoords = {//stuff}

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        getSlope(x[i], y[i], xcoords, ycoords)
    }
}

public int getSlope(int x, int y, int[] x1, int[] y1){
    //calculate slope using m = (y - y1) / (x - x1);
    double slope;
    for(int i = 0; i < x1.length(); i++){
        slope = (y - y1[i]) / (x - x1[i]); 
        return slope;
    }
    return -2;
}
```

This is all well and good but I am wondering how can I do this with a massive list of coordinates. getSlope gets called from another method that places a coordinate to be evaluated and this is running really slow O(n^2) i think (for loop in a for loop).

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Full disclosure: This is part of a larger assignment for school so I wouldn't like answers just thoughts related to time complexity and big-Oh.

Edit: for a bit more clarification.
Edit2: for a little more clarification.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code, since you're returning from the middle of a loop. Can you clarify? Also, can you elaborate more on the overall problem? It's easier to optimize things if you know the entire setup.

Comment: I see three problems with your code as it stands, before I'd even begin to answer your question.  (1) I don't think this compiles - you seem to have `return slope;` outside of the scope where `slope` was declared.  (2) If you intend to return an array of slope values, you need to create the array explicitly.  Otherwise, you'd only return the _first_ slope. (3) You need to cast one of the operands of `/` to `double` before you divide, otherwise you get integer division, which you really don't want.

Comment: Your function would be O(1) if it compiled. You didn't declare `slope` outside the scope of the loop. It also tries to return a `double` and is  declared to return an `int`. The function makes no sense as an O(1) function; why would you return the slope of just the first pair? Is this supposed to be a linear regression? You have *much* bigger issues than slowness for a large number of inputs. Work out the correctness first. Second comes profiling (maybe informally) to identify the areas of your program that are too slow, *with a clear definition of "too slow"*. Optimizing is *last*.

Comment: Also, in professional programming, probably the easiest way to optimize whatever specific operation you're trying do to would be to use a library specifically designed for it (assuming this is a linear regression or something). Lots of people have already solved the problem of doing complex statistics quickly and have probably created an open source solution for it. Using theirs would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: sorry i wrote the concept really quickly on my phone. The basic premise is this. I have a two methods each having a for loop calling for this function (Ill edit the comment). the main method goes through a list of coordinates, and the method in question compares the slope by comparing one of the coordinates two all of them on the list. i need to find the slope for each one then send it back to the original method.

Comment: So you're actually calculating `n(n-1)` different values?  OK.  Now how could this possibly be any better than O(n^2)?

Comment: @DavidWallace good point...

Comment: Which coordinate is your reference coordinate for slope calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the slope between two consecutive points in your coordinate arrays:

```
public void foo(){

    int[] xCoords = {//stuff}
    int[] yCoords = {//stuff}

    double slope;
    for(int i = 0; i < xCoords.length-1 && i < yCoords.length-1; i++){
        slope = getSlope(xCoords[i], yCoords[i], xCoords[i+1], yCoords[i+1]);
        System.out.println(slope);
    }
}

public double getSlope(int x, int y, int x1, int y1){
    //calculate slope using m = (y - y1) / (x - x1);
    return (y - y1) / (x - x1);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If what you want is to have multiple slopes with respect to a fixed reference point your method should return more than one value as shown below, but if you want to return a single slope from your method then there is no need for looping and your method does not also need to take array as parameter; you may just pass the two pair coordinates for a single slope calculation.

```
public void foo(){

    int[] xCoords;// = {//stuff}
    int[] yCoords;// = {//stuff}

    int referenceX = //set to your value
    int referenceY = //set to your value
    double[] slopes = getSlope(referenceX, referenceY, xCoords, yCoords)
}

public double[] getSlope(int x, int y, int[] x1, int[] y1){
    //calculate slope using m = (y - y1) / (x - x1);
    double[] slope = new double[(x1.length<y1.length)? x1.length:y1.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < x1.length && i < y1.length; i++){
        slope[i] = (y - y1[i]) / (x - x1[i]); 
    }
    return slope;
}
```